Plugins in the Enterprise Architect Not Working
I am creating an ADD in in my Enterprise Architect , I created the Addin, it was built successfully in visual Studio, Butwhen I Open EA For the testing of my Addin, it shows error:
Error - Missing (0x800401f3)
I tried Doc but didn't find Solution
